# Can the ratio of cpu:phantom:page be more than 1:1:1

Tags: javascript, performance, concurrency, phantomjs

Can I create more PhantomJS **processes** for each CPU or more than 1 **webpage** instance for each **phantom** process at a same time?

For example, 1:1:1 means: 1 pc with 4 **CPUs**, I spawn 4 PhantomJS **processes**, and create 1 **webpage** in each of the processes at same time.

It is a limit to concurrency.

Is there a good way to prove that can I change the 1:1:1 ratio and which ratio is good?

If the ratio of phantom:page is 1:n, do context switch race conditions occur and can this result in a PhantomJS error?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as three way ratios. A ratio has exactly two parties. Now that we have this out of the way, let's split the ratio.

We can define x:y with x number of available threads (CPUs/cores) and y number of PhantomJS processes. Then we can define y:z with z number of `page` instances.

#### Cores vs. processes

You can run as many PhantomJS processes as you like as long as the hardware supports it (mainly RAM). But for most architectures (all?), you will get a drop in relative performance (`y/x`) when `y > x`. When you have many processes and not as many cores then at least two processes must share one core (or thread if you have multi-threading). So those two processes won't be done as fast as the others. This has nothing to do with PhantomJS, but normal multi-process behavior.

If you have `y >> x` then even context switching of the processes might become a bottleneck and everything will be extremely slow.

Always look to spawn only as many processes as you have cores/threads (maybe even less).

For almost all cases, PhantomJS processes run independently by default. Only if the pages they are running on use localStorage, then you may run into problems. localStorage is always persisted on disk and there is no way to change that.

#### PhantomJS process vs. `page` instances

PhantomJS runs JavaScript scripts. Since JavaScript is single-threaded as a whole, you cannot get any parallel processing, but you can get concurrency through the normal JavaScript event loop.

PhantomJS supports multiple `page` instances per process and this works rather well, but of course since JavaScript is single-threaded, the execution of multiple pages is interlaced. This means that opening two pages at the "same time" should result in more or less the same time it would take to open them one after the other.

**This is not strictly the case**, because waiting for resources of one page enables other pages to do further processing. When pages are opened sequentially, then the time that one page is waiting for resources to be loaded cannot be used by other pages.

On the other hand one cannot use a large amount of `page` instances in one process, because the requests of the different pages will hinder each other. HTTP requests run on TCP. If there are multiple TCP which are fighting for the bandwidth then the overall efficiency of the connection is lower. But this should still be faster than the sequential case. This is why HTTP/2 (SPDY) is such a good idea.

**The concurrent processing is faster than the sequential way,** but it is harder to program managing multiple `page` instances per PhantomJS process (maybe even for multiple processes).

## Benchmark: multiple `page` instances

This script shows the two versions of requesting sites. The first iteration has largely differing results, because the cache is not filled yet. The cache cannot be cleared later, so every iteration uses cached resources after the first one.

```
var urls = [
    'https://google.com', 
    'http://stackoverflow.com/contact', 
    'http://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=15&sort=newest', 
    'http://www.spiegel.de/'
];

function sequential(callback) {
    var copiedUrls = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(urls)),
        page = require('webpage').create(),
        start = (new Date()).getTime();
    function sequentialHelper(){
        //console.log("seqHelp " + copiedUrls.length);
        if (copiedUrls.length == 0) {
            start = (new Date()).getTime() - start;
            page.close();
            callback(start);
            return;
        }
        page.open(copiedUrls.shift(), function(s){
            sequentialHelper();
        });
    }
    sequentialHelper();
}

function parallel(callback) {
    var copiedUrls = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(urls)),
        max = copiedUrls.length,
        pages = [], 
        start;
    function checkFin(){
        max--;
        //console.log("parCheck " + max);
        if (0 === max) {
            start = (new Date()).getTime() - start;
            pages.forEach(function(page){
                page.close();
            });
            callback(start);
        }
    }
    start = (new Date()).getTime();
    copiedUrls.forEach(function(url){
        var page = require('webpage').create();
        pages.push(page);
        page.open(url, function(s){
            checkFin();
        });
    });
}

var repeat = 5,
    current = 0,
    times = [];

function repeater(){
    if (current === repeat) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(times, undefined, 4));
        phantom.exit();
    }
    console.log("repeated: " + (current+1));

    var t = {
        par: (new Date()).getTime()
    };
    parallel(function(innerTime){
        t.par = (new Date()).getTime() - t.par;
        t.pari = innerTime;
        t.seq = (new Date()).getTime();
        sequential(function(innerTime){
            t.seq = (new Date()).getTime() - t.seq;
            t.seqi = innerTime;
            times.push(t);
            repeater();
        });
    });
    current++;
}

repeater();
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "par": 10653,
        "pari": 10652,
        "seq": 5304,
        "seqi": 5301
    },
    {
        "par": 2936,
        "pari": 2936,
        "seq": 5224,
        "seqi": 5219
    },
    {
        "par": 3167,
        "pari": 3167,
        "seq": 4478,
        "seqi": 4474
    },
    {
        "par": 2506,
        "pari": 2506,
        "seq": 6868,
        "seqi": 6862
    },
    {
        "par": 2479,
        "pari": 2479,
        "seq": 3753,
        "seqi": 3749
    }
]
```

Comment: Glad to see u again, @Artjom B. But your answer is still `x = y, y = z`. I expect `y > z` from you, because the event drive of javascript.

Comment: @soda You probably mean `z > y`. My reasoning is that, because JavaScript is single-threaded, there won't be any parallelism (only concurrency) to increase performance. This comes at the expense of programmatically managing those `page` instances in addition to managing the multiple processes. I haven't done any benchmarks, because as I said, this highly depends on the page you request and how you actually do manage multiple `page` instances.

Comment: Yes i mean `z>y`. program managing page instances is another issue.In my mind: `event-drive` means that when a event is waiting callback, cpu can do other things before next event loop, there has cpu interval.  I have not done any benchmarks too. Do you have some suggest about benchmarks? thanks~

Comment: Yes, concurrent processing with `y > z` is faster than sequential `y = z`. I added a benchmark.

Comment: Thank you again and sorry reply too late. At last, I found the problem. The key that make me slow, is the slowly responses sent by phantom. My test run on 4cpu 8G memory, run 260 of phantom processes at same time is the fastest. when process count less than 260, the system resource has free, and larger than 260, the total time cost time is surge.**So my conclusion is that when phantom wait for response, the process can surrender the system resource control, and phantom can break the ratio with cpu by general experience**